# Counting Consecutive Weeks based on separate numeric column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm working on a problem where the employees get a certain score each week. They will only have 1 score each week, being saved each Saturday. I want to count the number of consecutive weeks (working backwards from today) that they are above 50. If the previous week is not above 50 then they would have 0 consecutive weeks. If they've had a score above 50 each week for the past year, then they would have 52 consecutive weeks.

I've tried using the Row_Number() function to get this, but can't figure out how to incorporate the score as a factor in that.

This is an example of the data set:

```
EmpID  Last Week  Score   
A      7/6/2019   60   
A      6/29/2019  84   
A      6/22/2019  21    
B      7/6/2019   41    
B      6/29/2019  92    
C      7/6/2019   77    
C      6/29/2019  55    
C      6/22/2019  71    
C      6/15/2019  63
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
SELECT
    EmpID,
    EOW,
    SCORE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMP ORDER BY EOW DESC) AS RN
FROM a
ORDER BY EmpID, EOW DESC
```

But that only gives me a row count of each employee. I need the count to stop when their score is below 50 as below:

```
EmpID  Last Week  Score   RN
A      7/6/2019   60      1
A      6/29/2019  84      2
A      6/22/2019  21      -
B      7/6/2019   41      -
B      6/29/2019  92      -
C      7/6/2019   77      1
C      6/29/2019  55      2
C      6/22/2019  71      3
C      6/15/2019  63      4
```

I then need to get a single number of the consecutive weeks for each employee so that I can join the results to a larger query that pulls additional info about the employee. The scores are in a different table which is why I have to join it. The query should produce a result like:

```
EmpID  Last Week    Consecutive Week
A      7/6/2019     2
B      7/6/2019     0
C      7/6/2019     4
```

Does this make sense? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used conditional aggregation and running total.

The basic idea is:

If the number >= 50, the derived column will sum 0.

The consecutive zero(s) will stop at the first <50 value.

Then count the number of zeros.

I added the special case [group D]:

```
('D','7/6/2019'  , 51 )   
('D','6/29/2019' , 49)   
('D','6/22/2019'  ,52 )
```

There will be one single zero in this case.

If there is only one zero, I think the consecutive weeks should be zero instead of one.

I added [group D] into the test sample.

Try this:

```
SELECT B.EmpID,B.[Last Week], CASE WHEN B.TOTAL <= 1 THEN 0 ELSE B.TOTAL END AS RN
FROM (
SELECT A.EmpID, MAX(EOW) AS [Last Week], SUM(CASE WHEN A.COUNT1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL
FROM
(
SELECT EMPID,EOW, Score
, SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE >= 50 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY EOW DESC) AS COUNT1
FROM TEST
GROUP BY EMPID,EOW,Score
)A
GROUP BY A.EmpID
)B
```

Test Result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=788299c683aa56b542661dad6dd268aa)